# C# windows form datagridview cellformating event with date value and time value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my windows Form I have a dataGridView fetched from the MS Access database, it has a two column with TaskDate and TaskTime. TaskDate (data type = datetime) holds only the date and TaskTime (data type = datetime) holds only time. Now in datagridview cellformating event I want to make a label visible (visibility of label is false on form load) basing on the two condition current date and current time align with system date and time. Below is the code so far I tried, it doesn't throw an error but it doesn't even make the label visible. Need help badly :(

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                DateTime rowtype1 = Convert.ToDateTime(row1.Cells["TaskDate"].Value);
                DateTime rowtype2 = Convert.ToDateTime(row1.Cells["TaskTime"].Value);
    // Time formt is  dataGridView1.Columns["TaskTime"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = @"hh\:mm";

                if (rowtype1 == DateTime.Today && rowtype2 > DateTime.Now)
                {  
                  // label6 visibile property is false on form load
                    label6.Visible = true;
                    label6.Text = "Its time now";
                }

            }
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is not *only time*

Comment: @ Ivan Stoev okay, So how do I make it happen? any idea will be appreciated please.

Comment: maybe to convert both to string and compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to take and compare only the time part of the `DateTime`. Compare `TimeOfDay` property of both `DateTime` structures.

```
rowtype2.TimeOfDay > DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
```